# Data getting mixed when using Otto in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, otto

I am using Otto to get result to a fragment when an http request is made successfully.

In my application I have a viewpager. And because the pages are very similar, I use the same fragments in viewpager with different data, to download data.

The fragment methods looks like

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    MMApp.getBus().register(this);
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MMApp.getBus().unregister(this);
}

  @Subscribe
public void onHttpResponseReceived(VolleySuccesObject results) {
}
```

The data getting mixed, for example the result in page one is showing in page two
also.Does any one know how to solve this

Comment: This is because all of your fragments under the viewpager are subscribed to  VolleySuccesObject. So when the data is posted on the bus with this object all the listeners are called. I am also facing a similar problem and looking for a solution.

Comment: @MarutiB wrap the result in an object that knows which page it is destined for and check that value in the subscriber.

Comment: yup followed something similar :) Here is my source http://itbrokeand.ifixit.com/2013/11/12/android-api-calls.html

Answer (score 1):

This is because `ViewPager` keeps multiple fragments started for performance reasons. If you want to know which fragment is really visible, you should override [setUserVisibleHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29) method and register/unregister fragments at the bus there. Be aware that this method defaults to `true`. This means Android won't call it with true value initially. Thus your logic inside `setUserVisibleHint()` must check registration status and call `register()`/`unregister()` only when needed. Same is valid for `onStop()` method. If unregister has been already called inside `setUserVisibleHint()` then you don't need to call it inside onPause(), otherwise Otto will throw an exception.

Open source [TinyBus](https://github.com/beworker/tinybus) uses Otto-like API and has a special method called `hasRegistered(Object)` intended exactly for this situation, to check whether given object is registered to the bus or not.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. As @sergej shafarenka pointed out, viewpagers basically pre-loads a fragment based on your viewpager settings (which defaults to 1).

What's happening is your subscribed to the same object for each of your Fragments (i.e., `VolleySuccesObject` for your case). Now, while your Fragment A is in the foreground, Fragment B also gets loaded and so does its lifecycles, which where you register your bus.

At this point Fragment A and B (assuming, you're currently at Fragment A) are both listening to VolleySuccesObject.

The solution is based on your use-case, of course. My scenario is that I send a request for a `Person` object based off of an `id`. Now my Fragment A and B will receive these `Person A` and `Person B`, but both my fragments will receive this object. The `Person` object I get back doesn't give the Person's `id`, so that was a big issue since I had no way to find out for which the Person object is for.

**Solution:**
I used a wrapper for my Person objects (PersonResponseWrapper) where my API Service responsible for returning this PersonResponseWrapper that contains both the `Person` AND the `id`. So when on my @Subscribe, I have this code:

```
private String mId; //id used for the API call

@Subscribe
public void onPersonReponseReceived(PersonResponseWrapper response) {
   if(mId.equalsIgnoreCase(response.getid()) { //Yup, this the Person object for me. Processing...
        process(response.getPerson());
   }
}
```

Hope this helped. This plagued me for days! Will answer this post in case someone encounters a similar requirement.